# String to decimal swift

Tags: swift, string, decimal

I am using userdefaults to save a decimal value of unknown length ( I.e. 51000000000) . Userdefaults does not allow for the saving of long decimal numbers, so I resorted to turning the value into a string and saving it. Then I want to re load the number however I have been unable to find a way to convert string value into a decimal. How do I do this?

Edit:

Code for setting the value into userdefaults:

```
let savedValues = UserDefaults.standard
savedValues.setValue(String(describing: buildingConstants.jitterClickConstantCost), forKey:"jitterClickCost")

struct buildingConstants {
     static var jitterClickConstantCost = Decimal()
}
```

Comment: Start by showing your code for converting the number to a string before storing it in user defaults.

Comment: @rmaddy I have done that

Comment: 1. What is `buildingConstants.jitterClickConstantCost`? How is it declared? 2. Never use `setValue(forKey:)` on `UserDefaults`. Use the proper, non-KVC methods to store data in user defaults.

Comment: @rmaddy sorry, I've made it clearer, but I don't know what "non-KVC" methods means

Comment: Look at the documentation for `UserDefaults`. Note that there is no such method listed as `setValue(forKey:)`. Only use the ones listed in the documentation.

Comment: @rmaddy surely if there isn't a method documented such as that, it wouldn't work. But it does?

Comment: It's provided through a protocol related to key-value coding (KVC). You don't want to be using here.

Comment: Have you tried `Decimal(string: ...)` ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can try the default initializer for Decimal with a string parameter

here is an example

```
let decimal: Decimal = 51000000000
let str = String(describing: decimal)

let savedValues = UserDefaults.standard

savedValues.set(str, forKey:"jitterClickCost")
savedValues.synchronize()

let value = savedValues.string(forKey: "jitterClickCost") ?? "0"

let result = Decimal(string: value)
```

Comment: this worked for me but what is the point in adding the  '?? "0"' part at the end of the reloading of the value

Comment: so i wouldn't need to force cast it when passing it to Decimal initializer (it's just a default value)

Comment: ?? "0" means if null return "0"